# extra text is added to GUI in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have below code for reading an excel file, do a simple calculation and display the result in GUI.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
window = Tk()
window.title("Welcome Husnain Iqbal")
window.geometry('500x500')
def file_opener():
    input = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", ".xlsx .xls")])
    cf = pd.read_excel(input,sheet_name = "Classroom")
    mob = cf['Total Number Of Participants']*425
    label = Label(window, text="Participants Mobilization Claim is Rs." + str(mob))
    label.pack()
    
    acc = cf['Total A/C Opened']*25
    label2 = Label(window, text=acc,relief=RAISED)
    
    label2.pack()
    
    
    
x = Button(window, text ='Select File', command = lambda:file_opener())
x.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
x.pack()


mainloop()
```

It is adding and extra `0` and `type` in GUI. How do I get rid of it. [image]

Comment: `str(mob)` is not the correct way to display the values of a `pd.Series` in a widget. You either need to join them as a string, or iterate over the values and populate one by one.

Comment: There is only one row.  what do u suggest

Comment: Then use `mob.iat[0]`.